# Can a ViewModel have a child that is also a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Can a ViewModel have a child (property) that is also a ViewModel in the MVVM pattern used to develop WPF applications?

Comment: By "child" do you mean "inherited from" or "a property of" the ViewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly acceptable to have a hierarchical relationship (Parent / Child) between your ViewModels.

```
MainViewModel
  -> ViewModel 1
      -> ViewModel A
  -> ViewModel 2
      -> ViewModel B
```

These will usually reflect the hierarchical structure of the UI:

```
MainWindow
  -> UserControl 1
      -> UserControl A
  -> UserControl 2
      -> UserControl B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a main ViewModel with other ViewModels, it is important to always set the datacontexts.